# AS3: weird getBounds() result

Tags: actionscript-3, get, movieclip, bounds

EDIT2: It seems that the big numbers are created because the movieclip doesnt hold any bipmapdata, but Im yet not sure about it, but my real mistake was that I just forgot "this" infront of one "getBounds" ... project size was to big and I couldnt find the bug =)

EDIT: tried to use seperate containers, for the movieclips, and did all this in the root class ... everything worked fine, when I used seperate containers and attached everything to the charakter class it got screwd up again

OLD:
Hey I am making a game right now and I want to get the bounds of the charakter body. 
To understand how I did set the whole thing up I explain the hirarchy.

The class of my flash document is "game.as". "game.as" adds a Child of the class Charakter
my Charakterclass has a Movieclip for every body part, for example the "head"
every bodypart has a movieclip which contains the picture of the bodypart, in this case "head".

When I now try to use the getBounds(head.mc) inside the "head" class I get really weird results. ussualy something around x=64001, y=64001, width = 0, height = 0;

I found a way how to solve this problem by simply using the getBounds(head.mc) function not inside the head, but inside the Charakter class .... but this is not what I actually want to do, I would like to use the getBounds(head.mc) function inside the head class.

Any ideas why the results are so weird or what I have to do? Im very thankfull for every opinion, because this doesnt seem logical to me xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From inside head_mc, try `getBounds(this.parent);` (you may want to test to see if the parent exists first) - this should give you the bounds of your head_mc as its container sees it, which I think is what you want, but called from inside head_mc, as you request.

bitmapdata is right, though - getBounds() can sometimes give some odd results. It looks to me like you might be asking the question before you add head_mc to the stage, and are therefore getting the undefined values for width/height/x/y.

Comment: thats what I thought too, that I asked to early and I was dealing with this problem for the last for hours ... probably I should just take a break and try it a few hours later because I am quite sure that I fully understood how getBounds() works .... thanks anyway man =)

Answer (score 3):

`getBounds()` is inaccurate. Please read the following posts to understand the issue.

**getBounds "wrong" results** ([*Source*](http://timetoflash.blogspot.kr/2012/01/getbounds-wrong-results.html))

> When getting bounds of an object relative to it's OWN coordinate system,
>   those values will NOT be scaled.

**getBounds() returning incorrect height** ([*Source*](https://www.mochimedia.com/community/forum/topic/as3-getbounds-returning-incorrect-height))

Comment: It is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Comment: oh thanks this is not what I was looking for but very helpfull anyways and Im sure this will solve a problem which Im going to encounter soon =D